# Could not find function 'fread' in R 3.4 while reading a big dataset

Tags: r, rstudio, fread

I have installed package "microbenchmark" and then run: `library(microbenchmark)`.

Now, I am trying to read a csv file, but getting the error: `"fread" function not found`.

```
setwd("C:/Data Analytics/R Assignments")
library(microbenchmark)
data <- fread("BigDiamonds.csv") 

Error in
fread("BigDiamonds.csv") : could not find function "fread"
```

I have been using R 3.4. Could that be the issue?

Comment: `fread` is in the `data.table` package isn't it? Have you loaded it?

Comment: Yes, looks like the issue is the absence of `library(data.table)`.

Comment: Use `data.table::fread("BigDiamonds.csv")`

Answer (score 19):

Try this. It worked for me

```
install.packages("data.table")
library("data.table")
data <- fread("BigDiamonds.csv")
```